# Scheduling Zend Project in localhost, Xampp Windows 7 machine

Tags: zend-framework, xampp, localhost, job-scheduling

I am running Xampp on Windows 7.
I have a CronController in my Zend Project, with certain Actions containing code for scheduling!

How do i run my job scheduler using windows task manager or any other way.
I tried to google out but all i got was info regarding Zend job scheduling and Job queue.

So i have the url like - `http://localhost/myproj/cron/myaction`
How do i schedule it for testing purpose in localhost? As far is zend is concerned we need to access the urls to do a certain processing.

Could anyone give me info regarding how to schedule zend code in localhost?

Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

one the great tool is available for free on Windows, nncron. It uses the exact same syntax than unix' cron:

http://www.nncron.ru/

The lite version is the one I would suggest to use. The full powered version supports scripting in the config files. It could be handy but somehow over killed for normal cron jobs.

let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: Hi, i installed nncron on ma machine. I tried to start nnCron, but a cmd displays and goes off. How do i actually use this?

Comment: http://www.nncron.ru/forums/index.php?language=english you can take help from various topic, i am sure it will very help full to you